# How to get access token of Fitbit API using SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, okhttp, fitbit

I am trying to implement a Fitbit API using SpringBoot authorization code flow.

In this process I am able to authenticate the user with Fit API. Later, after successful authentication,
Fitbit directed to my redirect URL. Now to my redirect URL I could able get code. Now, using this code, how can I get `Access_token`?

Below is my code.

I am getting the following output

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=400, message=, url=https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/token}
```

```
@GetMapping(value="/")
public String data1(@RequestParam("code") String code) throws IOException {
 String bb="client_id={client id}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=
  http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&code="+code;
String encodedUrl11 = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bb.getBytes());
    byte[] decodedBytes11 = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encodedUrl11);
    String decodedUrl11 = new String(decodedBytes11);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType,decodedUrl11 );
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/token")
      .post(body)
      .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      .addHeader("Authorization","Basic {basic token}")                          
      .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Don't reinvent OAuth2; that "Spring Security OAuth2" tag that you used is there for a reason.

Comment: sorry, I can get help from you